# Reading floats and strings per line from file python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python. I am trying to read each line from a file and then for each line, I have to first read a string and then a series of floats. How can I do this using python-2.7?
An example of the text file:

```
phon_R01_S01_1    119.99200    157.30200    74.99700
phon_R01_S01_2    122.40000    148.65000    113.81900
phon_R01_S01_3    116.68200    131.11100    111.55500
```

I can read float numbers from file. I am currently reading each line from file but after that I am failing to extract/save/print both string and float numbers from line separately.

Edit1:
For clarification to @zipa:
I have tried below part to extract floats:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
li = []

for line in open("a.txt"):
    nums = line.split() # split the line into a list of strings by whitespace
    nums = map(float, nums) # turn each string into a float

    pprint(nums)
    #li.extend(nums) 
    print line

pprint(li)
```

I haven't done any part to extract string. I couldn't find any. Above code gives this obvious below error.

```
nums = map(float, nums) # turn each string into a float
ValueError: could not convert string to float: phon_R01_S01_1
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: @zipa I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could solve your issue:

```
nums = [nums[0]] + map(float, nums[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got the main idea to extract those.